# Python - Pandas - How to create date-time series with increment 0.01 second?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a date range with increment 0.01 second using pandas.

For example I have this information:

```
date = 2017/01/01
start_hour = 0
start_minute = 0
start_second = 0.006392
dt = 0.01
```

I have tried using

```
date = pd.date_range('1/1/2011 00:00:00.006392', periods=5, freq='s')
```

and the result is:

```
   2011-01-01 00:00:00.006392
   2011-01-01 00:00:01.006392
   2011-01-01 00:00:02.006392
   2011-01-01 00:00:03.006392
   2011-01-01 00:00:04.006392
```

From example above shows that time increment is 1 second.
I want to change the time increment to become 0.01 second.

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use millisecond as the unit, so 0.01 second is 10 millisecond, or *10L/10ms*; you can see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) for more information:

```
import pandas as pd

# use L
pd.date_range('1/1/2011 00:00:00.006392', periods=5, freq='10L')
# DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01 00:00:00.006392', '2011-01-01 00:00:00.016392',
#                '2011-01-01 00:00:00.026392', '2011-01-01 00:00:00.036392',
#                '2011-01-01 00:00:00.046392'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='10L')

# use ms
pd.date_range('1/1/2011 00:00:00.006392', periods=5, freq='10ms')
# DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01 00:00:00.006392', '2011-01-01 00:00:00.016392',
#                '2011-01-01 00:00:00.026392', '2011-01-01 00:00:00.036392',
#                '2011-01-01 00:00:00.046392'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='10L')
```